# Necessity of National identity card number in UK visa application

Tags: visas, uk, applications, russian-citizens

I am Russian citizen and have a national passport number, should I add this number to national identity card point in UK visa application?
I am applying for UK Short-term study visa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are separate fields for the National ID card and passport details. Enter both if you have both.

Comment: You did not understand the quiestion:

Comment: I mean, while there is a passport details field where I put International Passport details there is also National ID card in application - is it a national passport or not?

Comment: @pure_true If it’s used for internal identification purposes I’d say yes. Have you checked with the consulate where you’ll be applying?